# How to do Sumif using non-adjacent values in excel only using one instance of unique value matches

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, sumifs

I have data that looks like this in Excel (like a Gant Chart):

```
           Column A      Column B                Column C
           Step 1        Days to Complete        Requires Step First

row 1       1.1               2
row 2       1.2               1
row 3       1.3               1                     1.1
row 4       1.4               0
row 5       1.5               1                     1.1
```

You can start steps 1.1, 1.2, and 1.4 right away, but you have to complete step 1.1 before you can start steps 1.3 or 1.5.  What can I use to get the TOTAL DAYS TO COMPLETE = 3 result in a cell somewhere in my spreadsheet?  I've tried sumif but my column A and column C values do not match adjacent to each other in each row.  Plus, if it says step 1.1 in column C twice I only want it to add the value in row 1 column B one time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use two columns I would do this, first check column C with an if and if it is blank give a cell the value of column B:

```
=IF(C1 = "", B1, 0)
```

And then when you have applied this to match with your data you can sum that column in a cell by using:

```
=SUM(D1:D10)
```